# Is it possible to convert a ghost page (created automatically by open-graph tags) to a normal page?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to convert a ghost page (created automatically by open-graph tags) to a normal page? Or at least maybe transfer Likes?

I have created an username for it so now is "accessible" by going to facebook/pagename but still doesn't work as it should.

There is also an App for that page and haven't find yet an ideea how to attach it ("Go to app" button).

Comment: Did you ever manage to find out how to do this? I also have a page which was automatically created but it doesn't behave like a normal page (can't edit description, etc.). Many thanks

Comment: Actually no, I give up back then. But I've noticed a [new option](http://d.pr/i/zTqQ) recently.  
More information available [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem for our automatically created page by creating a new 'proper' page, then merging the previous 'ghost' page with the new page. The merging process transfered the likes to the new page, but didn't transfer content (status updated etc.).

More information here: [Facebook automatically created a fan page which I can't edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303466/facebook-automatically-created-a-fan-page-which-i-cant-edit/13273725#13273725)

I hope this helps.