# Facebook automatically created a fan page which I can't edit

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-page, social-media

We launched a website which uses the Facebook open graph and like buttons to share content on Facebook etc. One of the open graph tags includes information about the Facebook IDs of the website owners (`<meta property="fb:admins" content="..."/>`), so these were included. I am one of the admins, and when I liked the web page myself Facebook automatically created a fan page. This is OK, and we are going to keep the fan page, but I can't seem to edit it.

Is there any way to edit a Facebook page which was automatically created?

Comment: This functionality is deprecated and will be removed in a few months, there's a migration guide here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/

Comment: Thanks for the info but there is no 'Migrate banner' on our page, so it's like it's already a Facebook page - I just can't edit it. We also don't have an app ID for our website (as I didn't think we'd need one - we're only using like buttons). Is there something I'm missing? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by creating a new Facebook page then merging the old, uneditable page (which was automatically created in the first place) with the new page. From the new page I created I went to:

**Edit page** > **Update info** > **Resources** > **Request to merge duplicate pages**.

Select the old page and merge it to the new one. All the updates and pictures from the old page were lost (this wasn't really a problem) but the likes were merged into the new page. It also asked which username (which forms the Facebook.com URL) I would like to use for the new combined page, so I selected the username of the old page as this is what everyone was used to. At the end of this process I have a Facebook page, with the same likes and same URL as before which I can now edit.

I hope this helps.